# Finding proper subset of elements using relational algebra

Tags: relational-algebra

I have one table called Exams composed by the columns student and exam and i need to find all the students that took a proper subset of the Exams taken by the student A.

A sample of data could be:

```
student exam
A       1
A       2
B       1
B       3
C       1
C       2
D       1
```

And the result should be

```
student
D
```

Because only D took a proper subset of the exams taken by A, B is not in the result because he took an exam that A has not taken

What i came up with so far is:

take all the exams that the student A has taken

```
examsA ← π exam (σ student='A' (Exams))
```

divide the Exams relation by the exams the student A as taken

```
studentsNoGood ← Exams ÷ examsA
```

now i have all the students that took exactly the same exams and those who took more exams,
by substracting i find only those who took less exams and those who did not take a subset of the student 'A' exams.

```
lessExamsOrNotSubset ← Exams - studentNoGood
```

And then im stuck on how to differentiate those with less exams and those who took unrelated exams

With 'a proper subset' i mean that with 2 sets D and E, D is a proper subset of E iff D is contained in E and D is not equal to E, so there is an element of E that is not in D.

I am using the relational algebra found in the book Fundamentals of Database Systems (Elmasri, Navathe). page 239

Comment: There are many RAs (relational algebras). They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give a reference and/or definition for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the students that took exams unrelated to those of A first find those exams:

```
R1 ← π exam (Exams) - examsA
```

then find the students with at least one exam in this set:

```
studentsUnrelated ← π student (Exams ⨝(Exams.exam = R1.exam) R1)
```

Then you can remove also these students to find those that have taken only a proper subset of the exams of A.